# Makefile devolvendo erro "Missing Separator"

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Estou a tentar executar um makefile que compile programas em 'C'.

```
TARGET=client server 
CC= gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g 
LDFLAGS = -lm -pthread -lncurses
DEPS = util.h

normal: $(TARGET)

client: client.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) client.c -o client $(LDFLAGS)

server: server.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) server.c -o server $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

Mas o seguinte erro é devolvido quando executo no terminal (make client):

> ```
> Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.
> ```

Comment: Não é "missing separator"?

Comment: o título tá diferente do que você afirma

Comment: Sim , meu erro. é mesmo missing separator

Comment: Você usou espaços para determinar a linha de código a ser executada?

Answer (score 4):

Este erro é bem comum quando você usa espaço ao invés de *tab* para determinar uma ação.

Você pode verificar se usou *tab* ou espaço usando essa linha de comando no terminal:

```
cat -e -t -v  makefile
```

Se *tab* foi utilizado irá aparecer `^I` caso contrário ficará em branco.

Ex. na primeira ação o *tab* está correto e no segundo não:

```
$(FILE).tex: $(FILE).Rnw$
^IRscript -e "knitr::knit('$<')"$
$
$(FILE).tex: $(FILE).Rnw$
  Rscript -e "knitr::knit('$<')"$
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16945143/6532002